# Search using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP, and I'm trying to create CRUD with a search using PDO. But I got a problem with my code. When I filtered the data the fetch result didn't return in the HTML table output. Instead, the result data returning on a separate table. I hope someone can help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Here is my **search.php** code

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> First name</th>
            <th> Last name</th>
            <th> Age</th>
            <th> Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
            $keyword=$_POST['keyword'];
            $query=$dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE '$keyword' or last_name LIKE '$keyword' or age LIKE '$keyword' or email LIKE '$keyword' ");

            $query->execute();

            while($row=$query->fetch()) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['first_name']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['last_name']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['age']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>
                </tr>

                <?php  } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<?php
} else ?>
   <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> First name</th>
            <th> Last name</th>
            <th> Age</th>
            <th> Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $query=$dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
            $query->execute();
            while($row=$query->fetch()) {
                ?>
                <tr> 
                    <td> <?php echo $row['first_name']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['last_name']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['age']; ?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>  
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

Here is my **index.php** code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index Php</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Firstname </label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Lastname </label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Age </label>
            <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </form>
    <br />

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="keyword"/>
        <button name="search"> Search </button>
    </form>

    <br /> <br />
    <?php include('search.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying that when the search result html is printed, there's a table at the top with the header row, and then _another_ table below it with the data rows?

Comment: @JakeParis yeah you are right.

Comment: Can you please copy the resulting html from a search and paste it here? I'm pretty sure your issue is that the html for the table is being put together wrong. I can't see any problems in the search.php code, but that's probably what's going on. Is it possible that your database values contain any html?

Comment: @JakeParis Here it is. It is just my sample for my practice :)

`First name Last name Age  Email
samplie samplie 23 samplie@gmail.com`

Answer (score -1):

If a browser sees that the html for a `<table>` element is broken, it can lead to unexpected results. One of those results can be that some of the elements get "hoisted" out of the original table element into a separate one. I believe that is what is happening here.

You should look carefully at your html output and determine if there are any missing or extra tags. Likely, you have an tag somewhere that is an invalid child of a `<table>` or `<tr>`.

Also, you can't use the developer tools for this, as that will show the "corrected" html, not the original html.

Answer (score -2):

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="keyword"/>
    <button name="search"> Search </button>
</form>
```

I didn't go through all the codes but i saw this: you are missing form action which should be search.php

Comment: No... If you look at the bottom of the OP's html, `search.php` is a php include there. So the `<form>` is correctly submitting to it's own self.